# How to make salary/location filters for Wordpress Plugin Job manager

Tags: wordpress

I am working on WordPress project and i am using **Job Manager** plugin in this project. Can any one tell me how to make salary/location filters in front end for WordPress **job manager** plugin. I have tried to start work on it by myself but didn't find that salary column in wp database for which i can make checks for filter because this plugin save all its settings in serialized form in database.
can any one guide me or give me any solution about this..?